# Telegraf cannot connect to RabbitMQ

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, telegraf

I am trying to set up telegraf to collect sensor data from my RabbitMQ and forward it into two different InfluxDBs.

However, I am not able to get the connection between RabbitMQ and Telegraf working:

```
[inputs.rabbitmq] Error in plugin: Get "http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:15672: connect: connection refused
```

Opening 127.0.0.1:15672 in my webbrowser works, after intial authentication. Doing a

```
curl -u test:test 'http://localhost:15672/api/queues/'
```

yields a proper looking output.

Telegraf config:

```
[[inputs.rabbitmq]]
  ## Management Plugin url. (default: http://localhost:15672)
  url = "http://localhost:15672"
  ## Tag added to rabbitmq_overview series; deprecated: use tags
  # name = "rabbitmq"
  ## Credentials
  username = "test"
  password = "test"
```

My RabbitMQ instance is set up with docker compose, here is the snippet:

```
version: '3.7'
services:      
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.7-management-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
    networks:
      - testnet
```

Telegraf was set up with:

```
docker run -d --name=telegraf -v ${PWD}:/var/lib/influxdb --net=testnet telegraf:latest
```

The telegraf set up was based on an official guideline from the Influx team. I realize that my telegraf.conf file cannot be stored in ${PWD}, so I always copied my modified file into the docker container to /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf. I know that the correct config file is used based on different log output from changes.

I have checked docker network inspect testnet and can verify that all containers run in the same network.

I have no more ideas left, why my connection is constantly refused....

Any help is appreciated!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I can get the connection to work if you remove the network flag. Is there a reason you need to use a network? I am getting 401's unauthorized now but nonetheless it's accessible.

```
version: '3.7'
services:      
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.7-management-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'
```